# Unable to logically adress x,y-values of rasterToPoints extraction

Tags: r, logical-operators, r-raster

I am unsure how to describe this problem. I have a feeling it is trivial but I cannot get a hold of it.

I have a stack of raster objects (object `NDVI`). From these I extracted `x` and `y` coordinates using `rasterToPoints`

```
xycoord1 <- rasterToPoints(NDVI)
xycoord <- xycoord1[,c(1:2)]
```

Along the pre-processing I kicked out several unusable pixels and ended up with:

```
> str(xycoord.short)
 num [1:20054, 1:2] 3802292 3802523 3802755 3802987 3803218 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:2] "x" "y"
```

No I simply want to find a certain `x` and `y` coordinate.
e.g.

```
> which(xycoord.short[,1]==3802292)
integer(0)
```

But I seem unable to "get hold" of the values inside for example one column.

```
> xycoord.short[,1][1]
[1] 3802292
> xycoord.short[,1][1]==xycoord.short[,1][1]
[1] TRUE
> xycoord.short[,1][1]==3802292
[1] FALSE
```

Can anyone help me along this problem? I just don't find the problem. Does it have to do with initial extraction through `rasterToPoints`? Thanks!

EDIT:
dput output for the first 10 rows of my xy-coordinates

```
xy <- structure(c(3802291.63636448, 3802523.29272274, 3802754.94908101, 
                 3802986.60543927, 3803218.26179754, 3803449.9181558, 3803681.57451406, 
                 3803913.23087233, 3804144.88723059, 3804376.54358886, -49690.2888476191, 
                 -49690.2888476191, -49690.2888476191, -49690.2888476191, -49690.2888476191, 
                 -49690.2888476191, -49690.2888476191, -49690.2888476191, -49690.2888476191, 
                 -49690.2888476191), .Dim = c(10L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, 
                                                                         c("x", "y")))
```

EDIT2:
After posting the dput output it makes sense, as the values are obviously rounded. 
Using the exact numbers works...

```
> any(xycoord.short[,1]==3802291.63636448)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Ah! There's the problem. Let me edit my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have here is a rounding "problem". Your coordinates are in what we call "double" (10.3 is a double) but you're trying to subset based on an integer (say 10). What you can do here is round to `n` places and subset based on that.

For instance, let's check eight digits.

```
format(xy, digits = 8)

      x             y            
 [1,] "3802291.636" " -49690.289"
 [2,] "3802523.293" " -49690.289"
 [3,] "3802754.949" " -49690.289"
 [4,] "3802986.605" " -49690.289"
 [5,] "3803218.262" " -49690.289"
 [6,] "3803449.918" " -49690.289"
 [7,] "3803681.575" " -49690.289"
 [8,] "3803913.231" " -49690.289"
 [9,] "3804144.887" " -49690.289"
[10,] "3804376.544" " -49690.289"
```

So in essence, when you're looking for `3802292` it doesn't find it because it's actually `3802291.636...`.

You can either specify exact coordinate up to x places correct, or perhaps round your number and work on that. Or you could specify a range of values that would encompass your desired value(s).

Comment: I wanted to get the index for which e.g. a column is a certain value, this is why I used `which()`. . For example this should be `TRUE` for the first value `> head(xycoord.short[,1]==3802292)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE`.    But also subsetting does not work (e.g. `> xycoord.short[xycoord.short[,1]==3802292,]
     ` does not give results. It does somehow not recognize the first value as `3802292`

Comment: @Katharina can you share a small portion of your dataset? You can use `dput`. Use edit button to add this to your question.

Comment: good idea, I did so (see edit). Ah, I think I see the problem, looks like they are rounded ....

Comment: Including more digits it works now ;-) Thanks for the help!